# How to pull specific commits in git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

My branch is behind by origin by 5 commits.

```
muralish@vnc9[~/git/task](task-68↓3| ✓)$git status
# On branch task-68
# Your branch is behind 'origin/task-68' by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
muralish@vnc9[~/git/task](desflow-68↓3| ✓)$
```

These commits are A-> B-> C -> D ->E. How can I  get only the changes related to commit C to the working directory.

It tried git rebase -i but won't list that commit at all. It outputs the below informarion.

```
   noop

   # Rebase 484a22b..b7fa802 onto 484a22b
   #
   # Commands:
   #  p, pick = use commit
   #  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
   #  e, edit = use commit, but stop f
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to pull a single commit, maybe try `cherry-pick`?

Comment: I tried that but it will stage those changes again to commit, even after unstaging the changes it won't be clear if this change was made locally or cherry-picked.

Comment: By 'made locally' you mean before or after cherry-picking?

Comment: It seems you are working in a team, and origin/task-68 is updated beyond your local tracking branch. You only want one of the 5 commits locally. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
git cherry-pick <C-sha>
```

If you don't want these changes to be stored as a new commit use

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

The changes will then be neither staged nor committed.

**Update:**

If you want your own branch to *appear* to have merged those 5 commits from task-68 while *in reality* it would have only commit C you can write (after cherry-picking):

```
git merge -s ours task-68
```

**Update-2:**

It is a common practice to keep your local `task-68` branch identical to `origin/task-68`, so if you want to omit some commits from the parent branch, it is a good idea to fork it beforehand:

```
git checkout -b task-68-wip
```

After this, proceed with cherry-picking and merging as described above.

Comment: Yes this works, or even I can ignore commit itself while cherrying pick -n option. But the working directory won't be clean. Someone looking at it thinks. There has been one local change and still 5 more commits to be pulled.

Comment: `muralish@vnc9[~/git/task](task-68↓5| ✓)$git status
# On branch task-68
# Your branch is behind 'origin/task-68' by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
# 
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Common.java

nothing to commit, working directory clean
muralish@vnc9[~/git/task](task-68↓5| ✓)$`

Comment: Who do you expect to look at your own working dir except for you yourself? Distributed version control system is about every person having his own working dir.

Comment: I think "git merge -s ours task-68" does literally what he is asking for. But i do think he needs more guidance on how to git branches to maintain local changes separate from the origin/* tracking branch.

Comment: Thanks @AntonyHatchkins Apparently I am doing this on a test instance which other users can access as well.